# Recurring Meetings in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, meeting-workspace

We used to be able to do recurring meetings in SharePoint 2007.

Where is this recurring meeting option in 2013?

I realize the meeting workspace template is gone in 2013, but where is the option to have recurring meetings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the calendar, when you add an item. There is a recurrence option at the bottom of the default form that says "Make this a repeating event."